# Metadata version mismatch for module ../../node_modules/ngx-webstorage/dist/app.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3 using Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

i am trying to use ngx-webstorage but i am facing an error, i am not getting where i am going wrong.. I am using Angular4, the errors are

```
Metadata version mismatch for module E:/mapery-v2/web_page/node_modules/ngx-webstorage/dist/app.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/mapery-v2/web_page/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/mapery-v2/web_page/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/mapery-v2/web_page/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Can anybody help me to solve this error.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Web",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "ngx-carousel": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import {Ng2Webstorage} from 'ngx-webstorage';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        Ng2Webstorage,]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `package.json` you are using `angular version 4`.

**`"ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1"` requires angular5**

So, either you have to **upgrade to angular5 or downgrade `ngx-webstorage` to below version**,

Here is what you can do,

**Uninstall `ngx-webstorage`**

```
npm uninstall ngx-webstorage --save
```

**and install `1.8.0` version**

```
npm install ngx-webstorage@1.8.0 --save
```

[Here is a link where you can find that version mismatch issue](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage/issues/77)